# Multiple @:build macros

Tags: metaprogramming, haxe

To give a class multiple build macros, I previously stacked `@:build()` tags. I updated to dev haxe, and now it's only recognizing the last tag. Was the syntax for this changed recently, or is this a bug?

```
@:build(Macros.thisMacroDoesntRunAtAll())
@:build(Macros.thisMacroWorksNormally())
class Test {
```

I don't remember what dev version of haxe I used to be on, but it was after the 3.2.0 master release.

Comment: Stacking `@:build` tags works on the June 16 compile (f386f74).

Answer (score 1):

It's a haxe bug, and it seems like [Simon is aware](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/commit/b5f326300654e58f20b2a0acc951e35779535d8d).

Oh well.